# flask-sqlalchemy: where to place db.event.listen()

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update a postgres tsvector column after each insert. So I declared this model structure:

models.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()


from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType
class TsVector(UserDefinedType):
    name = "TSVECTOR"
    def get_col_spec(self):
        return self.name


class Suggestion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
    combined_en = db.Column(db.String)
    vector_en = db.Column(TsVector)

    __table_args__ = (db.Index('vector_en_index', 'vector_en', postgresql_using='gin'),)
    

trigger_snippet_en = db.DDL("""
CREATE TRIGGER faq_en_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON suggestion
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
tsvector_update_trigger(vector_en, 'pg_catalog.english', 'combined_en')
""")


db.event.listen(Suggestion.__table__, 'after_create', trigger_snippet_en.execute_if(dialect='postgresql'))
```

If the app inserts data in a flask view, it does not update the tsvector column.

Where is the correct place to set the `db.event.listen()` ?

Comment: `after_create` is only invoked on table creation through the ORM, isn't it? So it should be invoked when calling `create_all` - have you recreated your database after adding it?

Comment: hmm, no its an existing database that now gets this new table. I cannot recreate the DB. Do you have an idea?